# Find a basis for $p \in P_2(\mathbb R) $ with $p(7) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Find a basis for the subset: $$ S = \{\;p \in P_2(\mathbb R)\;\; |\;\; p(7) = 0\; \} $$

I'm not sure how to approach this question.

$$
p(7) = a_0 + 7a_1 + 49a_2 = 0
$$
$$
a_0 = -7a_1 - 49a_2
$$

$$
a_1(-7 + x) + a_2(-49 + x^2) = 0
$$

Is this even in the right direction? I don't know what to do from here, nor how to proceed by manipulating the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: A polynomial $p$ has $p(7) = 0$ if and only if $(x - 7) | p(x)$. That is, if we can write

$$p(x) = (x - 7)(ax + b)$$

since $p$ has degree $2$. Now $a$ and $b$ give two free choices.

Comment: I tried that approach too, but I'm not sure what to do next...With a vector subspace, I simply rearrange one of the terms to be dependent on the other terms, and then find a basis. But I'm really confused here.

Comment: @tgun926 Take $a = 1, b = 0$ to get $x^2 - 7x$, and vice-versa to get $x - 7$. Prove that these are independent / span.